# Cordova Build Failed: Deprecated Gradle?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to create an android hybrid app using cordova.
I do not know much about it, I just create my web-based files under the www folder and run the cordova commands and I expect it to work. However, I've got this message this time and I do not know how to fix it.
Could you help me, please?

```
D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline>cordova build android
    Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
    ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
    Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 75

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No usable Android build tools found. Highest 33.x installed version is 29.0.2; Recommended version is 33.0.2.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 669ms
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline\platforms\android\gradlew -b D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
No usable Android build tools found. Highest 33.x installed version is 29.0.2
```

You need to open Android Studio and install build-tools v33+. Right now you have 29.0.2 installed and it requires 33.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio to have a fresh new install.
Now I get this:
D:\Users\Manolo\Documents\AppsAndroid\MusicTimeline>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Manolo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

Comment: Please validate question and create a new one